# Inconsistencia en resultados ofrecidos por php7 en servidores apache LAMP - WAMP al validar textos usando preg_match

Tags: php7, wamp, preg-match, lamp

Me encuentro en la fase final del desarrollo de un proyecto Web que va a ser distribuido como extensión de [zendframework](/questions/tagged/zendframework)v.3x, para ser instalado en servidores que empleen [php5](/questions/tagged/php5) o superior y [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) ([mariadb](/questions/tagged/mariadb) o cualquier base de datos afín si se cuenta con un driver  [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo) instalado).
Todos los tests realizados en entornos [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) han sido satisfactorios, hasta ahora. Para ello he usado varias distribuciones de **Bitnami LampStack** y he realizado los ajustes necesarios para que las diferencias entre **php7** y **php5.3+** no den lugar a problemas de incompatibilidad.
Hace aproximadamente quince días inicie pruebas bajo Windows. Instalé [wamp](/questions/tagged/wamp) y luego de resolver dificultades típicas como instalar la última versión de [zendframework](/questions/tagged/zendframework) mediante [composer](/questions/tagged/composer) inicié las pruebas del aplicativo web. Y, **aparecieron algunos problemas** cuyo principal síntoma es el siguiente:

Al validar, en el servidor, entradas de texto enviadas por el cliente se observan inconsistencias como la siguiente:

> LAMP califica valida la entrada del texto **título** mientras que
>   WAMP devuelve **La cadena *título* contiene caracteres no permitidos**

En ambos casos el servidor es Apache, los dos usan php7 y el código es ***aparentemente*** el mismo. (Digo aparentemente porque fue zipeado para simular su distribución en un archivo "dist.tar.dz" y luego descomprimido e instalado en los directorios **module** y **public** de [zendframework](/questions/tagged/zendframework) de modo que clone la estructura del paquete original.

Las trazas de depuración me condujeron a identificar que el método que devuelve salidas inconsistentes usa una expresión regular para validar si el envío del cliente posee las características requeridas para ser admitida. Es el siguiente:

```
<?php
/**
 * @id: global_utils.php
 * etc.
 */
namespace {
// ... algunas declaraciones (no pertinentes aquí)
// la siguiente definición se muestra partida usa sólo un renglón
// continuo sin operador "." entre cadenas
define ('RESTRICCION_BUSCABLE_TILDADA', 
        '/[a-zA-Z0-9\(\á\é\í\ó\ú\ü\ñ\Á\É\Í\Ó\Ú\Ü\Ñ\@\¿][a-zA-Z0-9_\°' 
        .'\«\»\ª\.\-\(\)\ \,\;\:\`\/\á\é\í\ó\ú\ü\ñ\Á\É\Í\Ó\Ú\Ü\Ñ\@\¿'
        .'\?]*/');
// ... otras definiciones y métodos utilitarios

/**
 * Método para sanear entradas enviadas por el usuario que van a ser
 * registradas en campos de texto en la base de datos.
 * @param string $palabra Entrada a sanear.
 * @param boolean $reemplazar si debe o no devolver todas las coincidencias.
 * @return string La cadena resultante de la comparación o '' si
 *                no hay la coincidencia esperada.
 */
function aPalabraBuscable($palabra, $reemplazar=FALSE){
    $totest = trim( $palabra ); $salida=[];
    //$regexp = RESTRICCION_ES_BUSCABLE;
    $regexp = RESTRICCION_BUSCABLE_TILDADA;
    $result = preg_match( $regexp, $totest, $salida);
    if($reemplazar){
        return implode('', $salida);
    }else{
        return ( ($result) && ( $salida[0] == $totest) ) ? $totest : '';
}

function validarEntradaEnCampoDeTextoSimple($entrada, $label){
    $textovalido = aPalabraBuscable($entrada, FALSE);
    if($textovalido == ''){
        // Envía al buffer de salida el error obtenido
        mensajeSys('El contenido en el campo '.$label.' contiene caracteres no permitidos'
                  , 'ERROR');
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE; // La entrada es válida.
}   
}// fin namespace
?> // este caracter de cierre no se usa en el original.
// aparece aquí para forzar cierre del bloque de código.
```

El código es aparentemente el mismo en el entorno Linux y en el entorno Windows. No obtante, ante envíos idénticos, desde navegadores firefox, chrome y opera, ejecutados en ambos entornos y enviando posts a ambos servidores, el servidor apache en linux devuelve TRUE para palabras tildadas mientras que el servidor apache en windows devuelve FALSE para las mismas palabras.

Nota adicional Ambos servidores usan explícitamente UTF-8

Tengo el supuesto, de que de alguna manera hubo cambios ocultos en el sistema de archivos que hace que los caracteres tildados no sean los mismos en ambos lados, pero de momento no se ¿cómo puedo enfocar un test de prueba de el?

¿Alguien podría ofrecerme alguna idea para buscar una solución?

### Anexo 1.

Al consultar acerca de [preg-match](/questions/tagged/preg-match) en la documentación oficial de php [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) encontré una manera de forzar la validación usando UTF-8, aunque no sea el tipo establecido, en uno de los comentarios: Se trata de incluir una especie de **cast** para forzar tipos incluyendo la cadena `(*UTF8)` al inicio de la expresión regular que se va a usar como patrón de validación. En el comentario se incluía una referencia a la página en **PCRE** dónde es documentado el uso de dicho mecanismo [PCRE(3) Library Functions Manual](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) y decidí probarlo (a sabiendas de que puede ser muy costoso en términos de recarga de procesos) pues mejor tener una **mala solución** que ninguna.
Hice los siguientes ajustes al código:

```
<?php
/**
 * encabezado ...
 */
namespace {
// Se reemplaza la antigua sección de declaraciones
(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/') ? include_once declaraciones.php 
                             : include_once windeclaraciones.php;
// se mantienen las declaraciones no afectadas por el fenómeno win
// ...
// el resto de código se mantiene
}
```

Hice el movimiento de las declaraciones que se vería afectadas al archivo pertinente **declaraciones.php** y en el archivo **windeclaraciones.php** aplique los cambios a todas las constantes para manejo de expresiones regulares que involucran uso de caracteres especiales (tildes, eñes, no alfanum que deben ser escapados, etc.) a continuación lo ilustro:

```
<?php
/**
 * @id: windeclaraciones.php
 * Declaraciones específicas para ser usadas en servidores Windows
 */
// Nótese el uso del cast (*UTF8) en el patrón
define ('RESTRICCION_BUSCABLE_TILDADA', 
        '/(*UTF8)[a-zA-Z0-9\(\á\é\í\ó\ú\ü\ñ\Á\É\Í\Ó\Ú\Ü\Ñ\@\¿][a-zA-Z0-9_\°' 
        .'\«\»\ª\.\-\(\)\ \,\;\:\`\/\á\é\í\ó\ú\ü\ñ\Á\É\Í\Ó\Ú\Ü\Ñ\@\¿'
        .'\?]*/');

// ... otras definiciones
```

Procedí a repetir las pruebas de posteo de entradas tildadas que debieran ser aceptadas como válidas y el resultado inconsistente se mantuvo.
Nota hice reinstalación completa y eliminé todos los cachés antes de ejecutarlas, para descartar persistencia del fallo por efecto de **esos indeseables fantasmas**. Este test puede ser indicador de que al expandir los archivos se generaron cambios en la codificación con que fueron guardados. (pero no tengo claro como probarlo).

### Anexo 2. Encontré solución al asunto de la inconsistencia.

Luego de haces una lectura juiciosa al manual: [PCRE(3) Library Functions Manual](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) pude resolver el asunto de la validación aunque por un camino costoso. Agregaré una autorrespuesta a este asunto.

Queda pendiente el tema de ***cambios misteriosos*** en los archivos de código **provocados por Windows**

Comment: ¿Esos datos que vas a comprobar provienen de un formulario? ¿De una base de datos? Ten en cuenta que Apache bajo Windows, por defecto, necesita configurar `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` y en el `php.ini` necesitas `default_charset = "utf-8"`. No sé si WAMP viene así configurado, pero una vez que tuve problemas con el juego de caracteres al montar la web en Windows fue por culpa de eso, el navegador web mandaba el formulario codificado en el juego de caracteres del encabezado HTTP y no del que puse en el HTML.

Comment: Hola @franmost, Gracias por comentar. Si viene de un formulario. Pero, **no se puede saber** en qué servidor ni en qué sistema operativo se va a ejecutar. Está hecho para que alguien lo descargue de un repositorio, lo instale dónde prefiera (con tal que ejecute php y PDO esté instalado para acceso a Base de datos) y desarrolle en Español (puede traducirlo  pues se incluye un API que soporta traducción) de modo que el uso de UTF-8 lo debo garantizar en el código.

Comment: Mi proposición es que pongas todo el código (HTML y PHP) al mismo nivel y que envíes las cabeceras adecuadas. La solución de modificar los parámetros de configuración en Apache o PHP es para evitarte código, pero se puede hacer en el mismo script y así lo he solucionado en el pasado (tras quebrarme mucho la cabeza tras pasar varios programas de Linux a Windows de manera infructuosa).

Comment: Gracias @franmost . De hecho todas las cabeceras dicen explícitamente utf-8. No obstante aparecen fantasmas en las instalaciones windows. La respuesta que puse el Domingo, y que estaba tratando de implementar no acaba de gustarme y es posible que falle, posiblemente la borre y la pase a intentos fallidos en los anexos a la pregunta. Por esa razón no la he marcado como aceptada. ¿Qué quieres decir con poner todo el código al mismo nivel?

Comment: Me refiero a que el script PHP esté en utf8, la conexión a la base de datos también y, lo más importante de todo, usar las funciones multibyte como [mb_ereg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-ereg-match.php) en vez de preg_match ya que ofrece la funcionalidad similar para cadenas multibyte (utf8 es multibyte, iso8859 no).

Comment: @franmost muchas gracias por la sugerencia de las funciones. Las páginas están en utf8, pero no es seguro que windows los mantenga. (ese es uno de los problemas) Voy a hacer pruebas y te comento porque mi solución no fue satisfactoria.

Comment: Lo más importante sería a mi parecer, que cambies los `preg_match` por `mb_ereg_match` para que sean compatibles con caracteres multibyte. Tal y como pone la documentación, lo de `(*UTF-8)` solo funciona si PCRE fue compilado con el soporte adecuado.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente @franmost Justo en este momento estaba revisando el módulo en que tengo el problema porque las soluciones que he intentado no son convincentes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta solución emplea una característica de **PCRE** que permite a los usuarios activar (forzar) la validación en modo UTF-8. Pero, que puede resultar costosa en términos de rendimiento cuando se aplica a cadenas largas. Tal como indica el [Manual](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt)

> If you are using PCRE in a non-UTF application that  permits  users  to
>          supply  arbitrary  patterns  for  compilation, you should be aware of a
>          feature that allows users to turn on UTF support from within a pattern,
>          provided  that  PCRE  was built with UTF support. For example, an 8-bit
>          pattern that begins with "(*UTF8)" or "(*UTF)"  turns  on  UTF-8  mode,
>          which  interprets  patterns and subjects as strings of UTF-8 characters
>          instead of individual 8-bit characters.  This causes both  the  pattern
>          and any data against which it is matched to be checked for UTF-8 validity. ***If the data string is very long, such a  check  might  use  sufficiently  many  resources  as  to cause your application to lose performance.***

En las pruebas encontré que forzar la validación UTF-8 usando el modelo

```
$patron = '/(*UTF8)' . $expresion_regular . '/';
// donde $expresion_regular es la cadena de especificación de coincidencias
// de validación.
```

No es suficiente. Los caracteres especiales **escritos de modo explícito** dentro de la variable $expresión_regular **no son convertidos a los valores UTF-8 esperados**, son convertidos a "dios sabrá qué" pues windows los puso en alguna de sus misteriosas páginas **ANSI** y la validación sigue fallando.
En consecuencia es necesario insertar valores UTF-8 explícitos para todos aquellos que se desee admitir o prohibir usando la notación `'\x{valor_hexadecimal}`.

> 1. Codepoints  less  than  256  can be specified in patterns by either braced or unbraced hexadecimal escape sequences (for example, **\x{b3}** or  \xb3). **Larger values have to use braced sequences**.

De modo que se hace necesario consultar la [tabla-utf8 de codificación de caracteres](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/) y preparar un juego de [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays) desde el que sea fácil extraer y configurar patrones a incluir dentro de las **clases caracter** a emplear en las expresiones.

A continuación presento parcialmente una reescritura de la 'RESTRICCION_BUSCABLE_TILDADA' presentada en la pregunta usando el mecanismo discutido como ilustración del mismo:

```
<?php
// reescritura de la declaración del patrón de expresión regular
// se invoca un método que aplica la tabla-utf8 a los caracteres deseados
define( 'RESTRICCION_BUSCABLE_TILDADA', expresionBuscableTildada() );
// ... líneas de programa
// ...
function expresionBuscableTildada(){
   $alfanum = 'a-zA-Z0-9';
   $acentuadas = acentosUtf8();
   $especiales1 = caracteresEspecialesUtf8_admitidosAlInicio();
   $especiales2 = caracteresEspecialesUtf8_interioresofinales();
   $caracter_uno = $alfanum.$acentuadas.$especiales1;
   $caracter_dos = $caracter_uno.$especiales2;
   $expresion = '/(*UTF8)['.$caracter1.']['.$caracter2.']*/';
   return $expresion;
}
function acentosUtf8(){
    $acentos_utf8 = [
        'À' => 'c380',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
        'Á' => 'c381',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
        'Â' => 'c382',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX
        'Ã' => 'c383',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE
        'Ä' => 'c384',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS
        'Å' => 'c385',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE
        'È' => 'c388',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH GRAVE
        'É' => 'c389',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
        'Ê' => 'c38a',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX
        'Ë' => 'c38b',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH DIAERESIS
        'Ì' => 'c38c',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH GRAVE
        'Í' => 'c38d',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH ACUTE
        'Î' => 'c38e',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH CIRCUMFLEX
        'Ï' => 'c38f',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DIAERESIS
        'Ò' => 'c392',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH GRAVE
        'Ó' => 'c393',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH ACUTE
        'Ô' => 'c394',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH CIRCUMFLEX
        'Õ' => 'c395',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH TILDE
        'Ö' => 'c396',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS
        'Ù' => 'c399',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH GRAVE
        'Ú' => 'c39a',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH ACUTE
        'Û' => 'c39b',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH CIRCUMFLEX
        'Ü' => 'c39c',   //   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS
        'à' => 'c3a0',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
        'á' => 'c3a1',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
        'â' => 'c3a2',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX
        'ã' => 'c3a3',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE
        'ä' => 'c3a4',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS
        'å' => 'c3a5',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE
        'è' => 'c3a8',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE
        'é' => 'c3a9',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
        'ê' => 'c3aa',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX
        'ë' => 'c3ab',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH DIAERESIS
        'ì' => 'c3ac',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH GRAVE
        'í' => 'c3ad',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE
        'î' => 'c3ae',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH CIRCUMFLEX
        'ï' => 'c3af',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH DIAERESIS
        'ò' => 'c3b2',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH GRAVE
        'ó' => 'c3b3',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE
        'ô' => 'c3b4',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH CIRCUMFLEX
        'õ' => 'c3b5',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH TILDE
        'ö' => 'c3b6',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS
        'ù' => 'c3b9',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH GRAVE
        'ú' => 'c3ba',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH ACUTE
        'û' => 'c3bb',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH CIRCUMFLEX
        'ü' => 'c3bc',   //   LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS
    ];
    return '\x{'.implode('}\x{', $acentos_utf8).'}';
}
function caracteresEspecialesUtf8_admitidosAlInicio(){
    // armar el array y generar salida igual que en acentosUtf8()
}
function caracteresEspecialesUtf8_interioresofinales(){
    // armar el array y generar salida igual que en acentosUtf8()
}
```

Aplicar el mismo mecanismo para crear otras expresiones.

### Importante:

Como va a haber pérdida de rendimiento se debe crear expresiones más cortas y tratar de hacer validaciones progresivas para intentar optimizaciones.